# Cordova App fails when started second time - gets stuck on db.transaction

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, sqlite

```
function init() {

    db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "mydb"});        

    db.transaction(function(tx) {
            alert("in transaction");
            tx.executeSql('select key, value from settings',[],function(tx,rs) {
                alert("success");
                keepGoing();
            }, function() {
                 alert("error");
            });
    }

}
```

If I start the app or the first time after I deploy it, it works well (In this example, 'in transaction' and 'success' get alerted. However, when I leave the app (via `navigator.app.exitApp();` ) and come back (without having closed it in the task manager), the transaction does not even start. Which means, 'in transaction' is called, but neither 'success' nor 'error'.

I have two solutions in mind. 
Either

- I force the app to get shut down whenever I leave it (how do I do that?)

or

- I expect that the app gets stuck with some transactions that did not end properly, so I try to close them whenever I leave the app (and how do I do that?)

Comment: What is that `window.sqlitePlugin`? Why not just the storage API?

Comment: The sqlitePlugin is an implementation of the storage API, AFAIN.

Comment: So you are using a 3rd party plugin? Try the normal `window.openDatabase` and see what happens.

Comment: does not make a difference

Comment: Hello Ferenjito, I am also facing this type of issue . so please  help me if you resolve it

Comment: hey vishal, its quite long ago and I dont remember it exactly, but I think the issue was something with the database settings  in config.xml